# Wordpress Permalink Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

For the Permalink on wordpress setting I have

> /%category%/%postname%/

This will show Post in different category like `/blog/post_title_1/` or `/event/post_title_1/`

but now I have some Custom Post type such as Photo Gallery with the postype = `photo-gallery` and this no longer works and gives a 404 page. I want to stick to the normal archive template of `archive-photo-gallery.php` as the default template to pull instead of trying to create a page template for this. how do I tell wordpress to be show the custom post type url like how it used to show up when you have `/%postname%/` in permalink setting?

Comment: Have you refreshed/flushed the permalinks since adding the CPT?  Try hitting Admin > Settings > Permalinks page (no need to change or save - loading the page is enough) to see if this solves your 404.

Comment: does not seem to work. it no longer matches the custom post type slug it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Permalink settings on WordPress only affect posts of the type "post". Not custom types.
For this you'll need to write a plugin or find one.